# What is the most stable modal dialog implementation across browsers to use from javascript for a web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, cross-browser, jqmodal

I'm using a lot of JQuery in a web application that I am building for a client and I want to find an javascript implementation of a modal dialog that is reasonably stable across the following browser set.

IE 7+
FF 2+
Chrome and Safari

I've tried a couple of jQuery plugins but there always seems to be artifacts in one of these browsers.

--- Edit

`jqModal` seems to be more stable but I have an issue in IE7 where the dialog immediately disappears after popping up. I suspect a js event isn't being canceled or something. I'll have a bit more of a play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) few times and I'm very satisfied. It is pretty configurable yet very light weight.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/dialog/)? I'm not sure what the support is for Chrome but I've had good luck with it for IE and Firefox and allegedly it works with Safari.

Comment: Chrome and Safari share the same rendering engine, so it should be the same for both.

Answer (score 1):

We currently use BlockUI. It's awesome, in word. Can be styled via css (of course), blocks any element and seems stable, certainly in block IE and Firefox....

If you need a hand with it, post and I'll lend a hand...

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: I tried it initially but haven't looked at it in a month or so. I'll have another look after I've finished with jqModal.

Comment: Finally a dialog that works with IE6 ontop of form elements! Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar exercise, tried most of the plugins I could find. I used YUI for quite a while with good results; the only issue I ran into was resizing centered modals, which is quite an obscure use case.

I ended up with http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/ , I'm pretty happy with it.